# apt-cyg install return md5sum error

Tags: cygwin, md5

Since the last time I reinstall windows, and then cygwin, apt-cyg stops working. It keeps telling me

```
"md5sum: standard input: no properly formatted MD5 checksum lines found".
```

What could cause the issue? And if I want to learn more about the error, where should I go and look?

---

Edit:
When I start to debug the problem, I realized that the md5 code generated was too long(128 char) for an md5 code(normally 32 char). Since I am using a 64-bit version of cygwin, it could be the source of the issue. But how to resolve it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since version 2.867, cygwin has move to sha512 checksum, however, the current version of apt-cyg is still using `md5sum` rather than `sha512sum` for integrity verification. That's what causes the problem.

To resolve the issue change the `md5sum` in line 323 and 326 of the file "apt-cyg" with `sha512sum`. It should work.

This issue has already been addressed by pull request #37: https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/pull/38. But the change has not been implemented to the master branch yet.

---

**Edit:**

If you edit the file with windows program, the line breaker might be changed and causing issues such as

```
/usr/bin/apt-cyg: line 25: $'\r': command not found
```

Because bash recognized the line changer as a command. I suggest using linux editor like vim, emacs or gedit for the changing. Or you may directly use the `apt-cyg` file uploaded in pull request #37: https://github.com/jfritz/apt-cyg/blob/97848cfa9ae05297c0b01daeb8ad08a70bc3b77b/apt-cyg

Comment: The newer apt-cyg file has slightly different line numbers, but +1 for pointing me to roughly the right part of the file, and the appropriate fix. For me it was 343 and 346, and I also changed the comment too because OCD.

Comment: Seems they fixed this in the newer version. Just reinstall [apt-cyg](https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg)

Answer (score 0):

The current version of apt-cyg is still using md5sum rather than sha512sum for integrity verification.

```
343:#digactual=`md5sum $file | awk '{print $1}'`
344:digactual=`sha512sum $file | awk '{print $1}'`
```

To resolve the issue change the md5sum in line 343 of the file "apt-cyg" with sha512sum. It worked for me.

Comment: Wasn't it taken down by DMCA's takedown notice already? The version you downloaded was probably quite old.

Comment: this version was  the  only one I  found. Initially  I thought  it  is  old  but  actually  its bigger than the  one  presented  in other  answers  if you  take in consideration line numbers.

Comment: OK, good to know it still exists... Somehow the lack of package manager about Cygwin really doesn't sit well with me...

Answer (score 0):

Execute this from your shell:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's{md5sum}{sha512sum}g'  /usr/local/bin/apt-cyg
```

Then retry.